# World Clock in Javascript not getting the hours properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, date

I have made JavaScript world time clock which is very basic. I made it work but there is a little problem with different cities hours are not updating as I want. For example Sydney time difference to UK is 11 hours so I added 11 + hours. I then added a condition to format the time to 12 hours format like this 
sydneyHours > 12 
sydneyHours -= 12;

But it is still showing 11 + whatever number of hours in localtime e.g(16:46:49);

Plus any suggestions for improvements will be appreciated.

Many thanks

```js
function timeNow(){
 var currentTime = new Date();
 var hours = currentTime.getHours();
 var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
 var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
 var meridiem = "AM";
 var isbHours = 5 + hours;
 var romeHours = 1 + hours;
 var sydneyHours = 11 + hours;

 
 if(seconds < 10){
  seconds = "0" + seconds;
 }

 if(minutes < 10){
  minutes = "0" + minutes;
 }

 if(hours < 10){
  hours = "0" + hours;
 }

 if(sydneyHours < 10){
  sydneyHours = "0" + sydneyHours;
 }

 if(hours > 12){
  hours = hours - 12;
  meridiem = "PM";
 }

 if(isbHours > 12){
  isbHours = isbHours - 12;
  meridiem = "PM";
 }

 if(romeHours > 12){
  romeHours = romeHours - 12;
  meridiem = "PM";
 }

 if(sydneyHours > 12){
  sydneyHours = sydneyHours - 12;
  meridiem = "PM";
 }
 




 var localClock = document.getElementById('localClock');

 localClock.innerText = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + meridiem;
 localClock.innerText += "\n" + "Local Time";

 var isbClock = document.getElementById('isbClock');
 isbClock.innerText = isbHours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + meridiem;
 isbClock.innerText += "\n" + "Islamabad Time";

 var sydneyClock = document.getElementById('sydneyClock');
 sydneyClock.innerText = sydneyHours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + meridiem;
 sydneyClock.innerText += "\n" + "Sydney Time";



 var romeClock = document.getElementById('romeClock');
 romeClock.innerText = romeHours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + meridiem;
 romeClock.innerText += "\n" + "Rome Time";
}

setInterval(timeNow, 1000);
```

```css
#localClock {
 background: #87D4ED;
}
#isbClock {
 background: #EDDB11;
}

#sydneyClock {
 background: #F27D66;
}

#romeClock {
 background: #F09E2B;
}

#worldclock {
 width: 800px;
 margin: 50px auto;

}
#localClock, #isbClock, #sydneyClock, #romeClock {
 font-size: 40px;
 font-family: arial, monospace;
    position: relative;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="worldclock">

 <div id="localClock"></div>
 <div id="isbClock"></div>
 <div id="sydneyClock"></div>
 <div id="romeClock"></div>
 
 </div>
```

Comment: I'm seeing it show the correct time. (E.g. 6:59:50 PM)...

Comment: To get the time for any time zone, use UTC methods: add/subtract the time from the realted UTC hours or minutes, then use getUTC* methods to get the adjusted time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial problem, related to Sydney Time is because you are not accounting for the fact your hours variable is going over 24.

When local time is in the PM, you add 11 hours for the time difference and then subtract 12 to try and convert to a 12 hour clock.

Here's whats happening

```
16 //local hours
+ 11 = 27 // time zone adjustment
-12 = 15 // attempt to convert to 12 hour clock
```

The easiest way to compensate for this is through use of the [modulus operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f59bza0(v=vs.94).aspx).

```
var sydneyHours = (11 + hours) % 24;
```

This however does open up a new problem as Sydney will now display `03:43:23 PM` when it is actually AM because your using a singular `meridiem` variable for all your timezones and if one of them is PM they all get set to PM. This would probably be a good situation for you to [learn the concept of objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). You can create a new object for each city and assign them their own `hour` and `meridiem` property values and then read them all separately afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

you may want to give Moment Timezone a try: http://momentjs.com/timezone/

reason: you will experience pain trying to figure out timezones for every country.

if that url is not working anymore (wich i do not expect) try their github repo: https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/

**another big issue with your code:**

never use `getHours()` etc. for this task. they will return the local time of the computer the browser is running on. use `getUTCHours()` etc. instead.
srsly. just give momentjs a try. you will literarily avoid lots of pain during the process of implementing timezones.

**timezone definitions tend to change from time to time due to politics etc. this tends to even change dailight saving time**

Comment: Usually I would 100% agree with you, that everyone should use a library to solve datetime and timezone issues due to the massive complexity of the problems at hand but I get the feeling the original code was created more for learning purposes than any real world usage scenario and they won't learn anything by just gluing libraries together.

Comment: @SimonWest from a learning perspective you are totally right. messing with "time" in general is a good thing for learning. looking back however i would have liked to have a library like that available for productive use. for trivial stuff i agree. for timezones i don't. especially not if i see someone actually using handcrafted timezone management in production (wich i've seen quite often). yes it does require some experience fiddling around with time to achieve something like this: https://gottz.de/uhr.htm but ye. most tutorials suck and sadly they are found quite easily.

Comment: This should be a comment, it does not answer the OP's question.